# closing php tag in string stops syntax highlighting

Tags: php, vim, syntax-highlighting

In my vim files, when I have a closing php tag in a string, my syntax highlighting stops at that point

Example:

```
<?php

...  Everything good up to this point

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>';

$foo = 'bar'  <-- starting here I loose highlighting to the end of the file

?>
```

I'm running version 7.2.245.  anyone have ideas why this happens?  is it only me?  or is this a known bug?

Comment: (1) Cannot reproduce this with vim: syntax highlighting keeps correct. (2) Belongs on superuser.

Comment: Vim 7.2.438 that works b.t.w.

Comment: @Wrikken How does a question (correctly) tagged `php` and `syntax-highlighting` belong on SU??? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: @tmp: OK, there seems so be a consensus according to meta it should be here. As it is just _using_ a program. I wouldn't have thought so, but as I'm not around that long I'll stick to the consensus.

Comment: I don't use vi, but some editors do that.. I use to write: $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?' . '>';

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you have the latest version of the runtime files, or at least the very latest version of the php syntax file.
- Try using [this alternative](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571) syntax file instead.

Answer (score 1):

It isnt a bug, you have actually ended the PHP string. you need to just break it up. Do like `"'.'?'.'>'` or something

Comment: Not true. PHP only honours the ?> tag outside a string context. Putting it in a string just works as expected. In other words, you cannot break out of PHP mode from inside a string literal.

Comment: Yes, just came across it, and it may be debatable behavior (e.g. I used to guess the same as what Mitch said), but that's actually wrong. What @tdammers said is still true 10 years later.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Notice the SO syntax highlighter stopped highlighting at that point too ;)

My windows editor does the same thing.

Comment: I hope it has other redeeming features, I have been searching for the last couple of minutes, and under debian I cannot find an editor which _doesn't_ get it :)

Answer (score -1):

Even PHP's built in function works this way (or used to for a long time)